# Add all array values before specific array value with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, for-loop

Within my software, I have a spread viewer which aligns pages next to each other. The number of pages can vary. Users can place notes on these pages. I want to be able to tell which page the note is being added to by comparing the x coordinate to the sum of the page widths.

For this example, let's say I have a 4 page spread. I build a js array `widthArr[]` which has these values: `[297, 300, 305, 410]`

So of course to following is true

```
widthArr[0] = 297 //page 1 width
widthArr[1] = 300 //page 2 width
widthArr[2] = 305 //page 3 width
widthArr[3] = 410 //page 4 width
```

**So if the x coordinate is 400, then I will know that the note is being placed on Page 2.**

Is there a way that I can dynamically loop through these pages and somehow check if x is greater than the width of all previous page widths?

I would need to check the following in this particular scenario:

Is `x > (widthArr[0] + widthArr[1] + widthArr[2])`? Then the user is adding a note to page 4.

Is `x > (widthArr[0] + widthArr[1])`? Then the user is adding a note to page 3.

Is `x > widthArr[0]`? Then the user is adding a note to page 2. If not, then the user is adding a note to page 1.

I was starting out with the following for loop.

```
var spreadPagesLength = 4;
var x = 400;
var i;
for (i = 0; i < spreadPagesLength; ++i) {

}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks so much.

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem. How do these pages get created or widths set? Surely can add identifiers to them at that point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a running total of widths you've seen so far, and `break` when the width exceeds `x`:

```
var widthArr = [297, 300, 305, 410];
var page = widthArr.length + 1;   // after the last page, as a default
var x = 400;
var totalWidth = 0;

for ( var i = 0; i < widthArr.length; ++i )
{
  totalWidth += widthArr[i];

  if (x < totalWidth)
  {
    page = i + 1;
    break;
  }
}
```